# How do I filter items by name and timestamp range in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to filter transactions by external id that fit in start and end date range. When I add dates within the range they don't show up. Here is my current code

```
filtered_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(
        organisation_id_from_partner=organisation_id,
        timestamp__range=[latest_transaction.timestamp, start_date]
    )
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why you use `start_date` as the "end date" of the range?

Comment: Thanks @WillemVanOnsem that was my mistake. I should have started with start date(smaller date)

Comment: so your question is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of dates in range to start with the start_date

```
filtered_transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(
        organisation_id_from_partner=organisation_id,
        timestamp__range=[start_date, latest_transaction.timestamp]
    )
```